# Ошибка линкера ld.exe и build-а проекта

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glut

В университете постигаем основы компьютерной графики при помощи CodeBlocks и библиотеки OpenGL.Мое стремление захлебнулось на этапе HelloWorld. ld.exe просто не может найти файл -lfreeglut. Часа 3 уже ковыряюсь в настройках.
это код, но суть не  нем:

```
 #include "GL\glut.h"

void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//рисуем треугольник
glColor3ub( 145, 30, 66);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f); //верхняя вершина
glVertex3f(-0.4f,0.4f, 0.0f); //левая вершина
glVertex3f( 0.4f,0.4f, 0.0f); //правая вершина
glEnd();
//////////////////////////////////

//рисуем прямоугольник
glColor3ub( 239, 211, 52);
glRectf(-0.2f, 0.4f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
///////////////////////////////////

//рисуем отрезок
glLineWidth(50); //задаем толщину
glColor3ub( 60, 170, 60);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(-0.9, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.9, 0, 0);
glEnd();

glFlush();
}

int main()
{
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 140);
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL window");
glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

ошибка выглядит так:

```
ld.exe||cannot find -lfreeglut|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
```

что я делаю не так?

build.log

```
    -------------- Build: Debug in aaaa (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -o bin\Debug\aaaa.exe obj\Debug\main.o -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib\libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib\libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../..\libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfreeglut collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: Писали где-то что надо заменить \ на /, но это в порядке.

Comment: Содержимое вкладки Build Log в студию.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat    https://bitbucket.org/pakitowka/build-log/src/master/README.md   как то так

Comment: Видимо не подсовываете `freeglut`.

Comment: в том-то и дело, что физичкски они есть, wiyard.script и второй тот файл правил. Можете на ты.

Comment: Почти уверен, что вы подсовываете freeglut, собранный не под ту разрядность (32 бита, а надо 64).

Comment: и в той  и в той папке закинул

Comment: все я понял. Вы оказались божественно правы

Comment: я закинул библиотеку 32-бит, вместо библиотеки 64-бит, которая находилось в отдельной папке.